# Angular 2 TS object array only defined while subscribed to service

Tags: arrays, object, angular, typescript, observable

I'm in the process of learning Angular 2 using TypeScript. So far I've written a little **API service** that uses **HTTP get** method to feed me json data using observables. Everything is working fine, I can use the data in my view, I can also use the data in my component, but **only while I'm subscribed** to the getData() method.

---

**Why is that and what other possibilities do I have to make the object array available to all methods in my component for easy iteration and management?**

**Example component:**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public someData: DataObject[];

  public constructor(private service: SomeService) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
    this.useData();
  }

  private loadData(): void {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(data=> {
      this.someData = data;

      this.someData.forEach(dataObject => {
        // this works fine
      });
    });
  }

  private useData(): void {
    this.someData.forEach(dataObject => {
      // dataObject is (of type?) undefined, why?
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because http calls are async. Your `this.useData();` does not wait `this.loadData();` to finish. This should work:

```
  private loadData(): void {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(data=> {
      this.someData = data;

      this.useData();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Can I make the loadData method synchronous somehow? I have 2 methods loading 2 different arrays of objects and I need to iterate over both arrays at once after they've been loaded. I'd hate to mix them up by loading them in a single method.

Comment: Rephrased: Can I wait and check for the data to be loaded to call my method afterwards?

Comment: I made a quick research about it sometime ago and as far as i know there is no way waiting for async functions. You are meant to implement logic in callback functions. You might wanna google it see if things have changed or not.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try googling now that I know the problem. Thanks!